# Selecting Node from xml file using xpath

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

My XML file is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Settings>
     <SurveySetting IsServeyOn="false" />
   </Settings>
```

I want to fetch the value of IsServeyOn.
I write the below code for that:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc  = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filepath);
XmlElement root  = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode node  = root.SelectSingleNode("//SurveySetting");
RadiobuttonSurverysetting.SelectedValue  = node.Attributes["IsServeyOn"].Value;
```

But sometimes it gives me error.. Node not found or NUll.
Is any other way to select the node?

Comment: There are other ways, but your XPath expression is valid, and `node` being `null` indicates there is no `<SurveySetting>` element in your document. Are you absolutely sure that element is always present?

Comment: As @FrédéricHamidi said,Before setting the RadioButtonSurveySetting, check the Value with null.If it is not null then set it.

Comment: First search this way to avoid `NULL`.. Use `//SurveySetting[not(@IsServeyOn)]`

Comment: @Babai, do you mean `//SurveySetting[@IsServeyOn]`, in case the element exists but its attribute doesn't?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes..I mean that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(filepath);
XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("SurveySetting");
if (node != null && node.Attributes.Count > 0 && node.Attributes["IsServeyOn"] != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(node.Attributes["IsServeyOn"].Value))
  {
        RadiobuttonSurverysetting.SelectedValue = node.Attributes["IsServeyOn"].Value;
  }
```

I have tried your code by putting some validations and it works fine in my application